# How to us PHP Values in Direction Google map API and load map on page load

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I want to use PHP values for start address and end address in direction google map instead of drop down list. My values are from database.

With code below the map is loading but not showing directions, I think the problem is with onChangeEvent function which I am failing to change to onload as it result to map not loading ;

```
<div id="floating-panel">
                    <input type="text" id="start" name="start" value="<?php echo $start;?>" />
                    <input type="text" id="end" name="end" value="<?php echo $location; ?>" />
                    </div>
                      <div id="right-panel"></div>
                        <div id="map"></div>
                        <script>
                          function initMap() {
                            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                              zoom: 7,
                              center: {lat: <?php echo $latitudee; ?>, lng: <?php echo $longitudee; ?>}
                            });
                            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

                            var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
                            control.style.display = 'block';
                            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);


                            var onChangeHandler = function() {
                              calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
                            };
                            document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
                            document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);


                          }

                          function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                            var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
                            var end = document.getElementById('end').value;;
                            directionsService.route({
                              origin: start,
                              destination: end,
                              travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                            }, function(response, status) {
                              if (status === 'OK') {
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                              } else {
                                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                              }
                            });
                          }
                        </script>
```

Comment: Browsers have dev modes.  What does that show? What research have you dione?

Comment: I can't post here without doing research first, this is not an answer to my question

Comment: Correct, this is not an answer, it is a comment. I am commenting to tell you that a good question as per [ask] suggests you show some of your research so people who _do_ want to answer won't go over what you have already done. Which is exactly what happened with your first Answer. Posting a question on SO should come _after_ you have researched your problem so you have the best idea how to present it as a question.

Comment: BTW, I'm not the one giving you downvotes, but the downvotes are telling you the community thinks this question needs some work.

Comment: One thing jumps out at me: "I think the problem is with onChangeEvent function which I am failing to change to onload as it result to map not loading" Can you explain why you think this is the case? What steps have you taken during debugging led you to this assertion? How would we test this assertion?

Comment: The onChangeHandler Function is for dropDownList yet I am using inputs(textBoxes), if you can covert that to right format I can appreciate.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but make sure you [edit] the question when updating information; comments can be deleted. I think you are asking about events raised from UI changes? `onchange` should be raised once the element loses focus. But I may be misunderstanding the question. Unless you mean that `onchange` isn't fired if the element is changed in some other manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two hidden inputs (text) named as 'start' and 'end', than populate them with values from your Database

Comment: I tried but map is not loading, see what I was trying in code above

Comment: With the hidden inputs the map is loading but not showing directions